# HTTP 500 error when rendering template in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

This isn't a duplicate question. I've updated the flask code with the answers in the similar questions, but it still isn't working. I'm very new to flask, html and python, so I really do need help. I've probably seen my answer somewhere but haven't recognised it.

The code below doesn't render the index.html template. Instead, I get a HTTP 500 error (jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string'). I think the problem is in the .html file because when I render other index.html templates without changing my app.py code, the html template is rendered.

Here's the code in app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, abort

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    resp = make_response(render_template('index.html'))
    return resp


@app.route('/getTenants', methods=['GET'])
def dummy():
    data = ['Black', 'Blue', 'White', 'Pink']
    return jsonify(results=data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's the code in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/favicon.ico') }}">

    <title>Create Contract</title>

    <!--  CSS    -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'css/common.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'css/simple-line-icons.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />

<head>

<body>
<!-- Spinner -->
<div class="spinner global" ng-class="{'showing' : loading }"><div class="spinner-icon"></div></div>

<!-- Main View -->
<div ui-view></div>

<!-- Awesome Angular -->
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/libs/angular.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- AngularJS plugins -->
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/libs/ui-bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/libs/angular-ui-router.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/libs/ocLazyLoad.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename=js/libs/loading-bar.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- App scripts -->
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/routes.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/services.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/controllers.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/directives.js') }}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The traceback error is
`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string'`

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There's too much code here. Please cut down the template to the minimum to show the problem.

Comment: I've cut down the template to the minimum

Comment: Did cutting down help you understand it?

Comment: Can you add complete exception details and not just message

Comment: can you take out parts of the template and render the more minimal template, to find which parts of the template are fine and which are needed to reproduce the problem? That would focus you on a small section of code which might contain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Line 33 in your code `index.html` snippet:

Right after `filename` attribute paste `'`